# In TFS, How can I move a user from one domain to the other when the username is different?

Tags: tfs

I'm in the process of moving users from an "old" Windows domain to a "new" one and need to reflect these changes in TFS permissions.

I've been successfully following the instruction in this MSDN article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx

But I've stumbled into an end-case that the article does not cover. For some of the users, the username in the old domain is different from the username in the new domain and it seems that the `TfsAdmin.exe Sid` command does not know how to address this issue.

Does anybody know how to reassign the TFS sid from domainA\usernameA to domainB\usernameB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an IT guy but asking our resident god says that if you add the old SID to the new user in their SID history attribute then the the rights should resolve backwards. I know this is not TFS specific but I hope it gives you some clue to solving your problem.

He also said you need to ensure a trust relationship between the domains also.

Comment: Could you provide details on how to edit a user's SID history attribute? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I've just seen this. I'll ask for you.

Comment: Ok I've been told: Using a tool like ADSIEdit, navigate to the new  user object in question, and edit its properties. Then find the multivalued attribute called "sIDHistory" - I think the case is important. Then add any the old SID in there.